# how to get rid of Too many characters in character literal?

Tags: c#

I get the error `Too many characters in character literal` for the below code?how should I declare the buildserverlocation?

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string buildServerLocation = @'\\Location\builds682\INTEGRATION\ABC1234.QSC.0.0-000000025-P-1';
        char delimiterChars = '\\';
        string[] serverString = buildServerLocation.Split(delimiterChars);
        string serverName = serverString[1] + ".company.com";
        Console.WriteLine("build server name is " + serverName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `"`, not `'`.

Comment: you need to re-read on the difference between a `char ' '` and a `string " "`

Comment: MethodMan - whats the difference between char ' '  and string  " "?can you point a link?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228362.aspx reference for strings.

Answer (score 2):

This needs to be a string, but you've used the `'` syntax, which is valid only for a single character:

```
string buildServerLocation = @'\\snowcone\builds682\INTEGRATION\IPQ8064.ILQ.5.0-000000025-P-1';
```

should be

```
string buildServerLocation = @"\\snowcone\builds682\INTEGRATION\IPQ8064.ILQ.5.0-000000025-P-1";
```

This declaration is correct by itself, but you then go on to pass it to `split`. That's legal -- thanks Jeppe -- but it would be better to make it clear that this is an array with a single char:

```
char delimiterChars = '\\';
```

should be

```
char[] delimiterChars = { '\\' };
```

But the larger problem is that none of this is correct. If you're splitting up a path, **use a class dedicated to extracting data from paths rather than rolling your own**.

Also, not a super great idea from a security perspective to be posting paths of your internal servers on a public site.

Comment: The `Split` overload for which the array has the `params` modifier, is the overload that takes a `char[]`, so I think the original code was correct in that respect.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Good point, I had forgotten about that overload.

Comment: Eric,can you expand on `use a class dedicated to extracting data from paths rather than rolling your own.` with an example?

Comment: @user2125827: This isn't a tutorial site; nor is it a code writing service.  Do some research.

Answer (score -6):

This line is your problem:

```
char delimiterChars = '\\';
```

You can only have one character in a `char` literal. What you need to use as delimiters either needs to be a `string` denoted by using quotations marks.

```
string delimiterChars = "\\";
```

Note: This will work with little other editing, as `string.Split()` has an overload that takes a `string`.  You just need to define its second parameter, which in this case could be `null`.

Comment: `'\\'` is an escaped backslash character and it works fine.

Comment: In a string, yes.  I always keep the clarity of the code in mind, though.  To me, using double quotes to assign a char its value is a little more unclear when reading over the code.